# Finding the hypotenuse of a triangle using angles and segment lengths.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle, mixing-variables

In the diagram, $\angle CAB = 90^\circ.$ Let $D$ be a point on $\overline{AB},$ and let $E$ be a point on $\overline{AC},$ such that $AB = AC = DE,$ $BD = 9,$ and $CE = 8.$ Find $DE.$
[image]

[asy]
unitsize(3 cm);

pair A, B, C, D, E;

A = (0,0);
B = dir(230);
C = dir(230 + 90);
D = 0.6*B;
E = 0.8*C;

draw(B--A--C);
draw(D--E);
draw(rightanglemark(B,A,C,2));

label("$A$", A, N);
dot("$B$", B, SW);
dot("$C$", C, SE);
label("$D$", D, NW);
label("$E$", E, NE);
[/asy]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ywxi.png)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=AB = AC = DE $ and apply the Pythagorean theorem ${AE}^2+{AD}^2={DE}^2$  to the triangle $ADE$, i.e.

$$(x-9)^2+(x-8)^2=x^2$$

which yields $DE=x=29$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB=AC=DE=x$ then we have $DB=9 and EC=8$ which gives us $AD=x-9\quad and\quad AE=x-8$ and by pythagoras formula in $\triangle ADE $ we get that $${AE}^2+{AD}^2={DE}^2$$ which gives us $${(x-9)}^2+{(x-8)}^2={(x)}^2$$ and it simplifies to $$x^2-34x+145=0$$ which gives us $$x=5 \text{or} x=29$$ but as we know $AD\ge0$ $x=5$ is eliminated and we have $x=29$ which implies $$DE=29$$